# VBA Excel "Target" highlighted as "Compile Error: Sub or function not defined"

Tags: vba, excel

Maybe I'm dim but I can't see why I'm getting a "Compile Error: Sub or function not defined" error on the following code.  The compiler highlights the term "Target" as though I am supposed to define it.
What am I missing here? I thought it was a library missing but they seem to be okay.  Googling hasn't helped.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Employee_Entered()
Dim Employee_name As String

Employee_name = Target.Value

Target(0, 2) = Employee_name

End Sub
```

(Obviously I've cut out the rest of the code.  But this still gives me the error described.)

I'm using Excel 2010, Version 14.0.7165.5000.

Thanks
Tim

Comment: What is target here?

Comment: Seems like `Target` should be a range, then you want to repeat the value in that range into the cell 2 columns to the right?

Comment: You have `Option Explict` on so anything not that's not global needs to be defined with a `Dim` statement or it will throw up a compile error.  Maybe you're looking for `Selection`.  That doesn't need to be defined ahead of time.

Comment: I think you're getting confused with the Worksheet events such as `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` which does contain a `Target` variable.  In any other code you'll have to define `Target` yourself, or use `Selection` as Sobigen commented.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `Set` to suit your needs:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Employee_Entered()
    Dim Employee_name As String
    Dim Target As Range

    Set Target = Range("A1")

    Employee_name = Target.Value
    Target.Offset(0, 2) = Employee_name
End Sub
```